# Is there a pythonic way to extend a line in a graph from two datapoints?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

I've created a random walk dataset and calculatded the local minimimum and maximum points and plotted these on a graph using matplotlib. Im wondering if there is a way in Python to use the datapoints to create a line and extend this line for each period in the same "direction" as the previous two points. See the picture below. Any ideas how I can do this?

Thank you for any help!

[image]

```
import random
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

#create random walk
random.seed(1)
random_walk = list()
random_walk.append(-1 if random.random() < 0.5 else 1)
for i in range(1, 20):
    movement = -1 if random.random() < 0.5 else 1
    value = random_walk[i-1] + movement
    random_walk.append(value)


df  = pd.DataFrame(random_walk, columns=["data"])

n=3
# Find local peaks
df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]]['data']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]]['data']


plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c='g')


plt.plot(df.index, df['data'])
plt.plot(df['min'], '.r-') 
plt.plot(df['max'], 'xb-')

plt.show()


print(df['min'])
print(df['min'])
```

Comment: Do you want a straight line connecting each pair of points?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. The picture is fine. There are 3 red, 3 blue data points, a graph through these data points and some other red and blue structures. Could you more clearly describe, what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to linearly project using two (I'll use the first and last) local mins and maxes. So you have to determine those points, then fit a function to plot through them linearly, and plot that function with a set of points that extends beyond your data:

```
from random import random
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create random walk
random.seed(1)
random_walk = list()
random_walk.append(-1 if random() < 0.5 else 1)
for i in range(1, 20):
    movement = -1 if random() < 0.5 else 1
    value = random_walk[i-1] + movement
    random_walk.append(value)


df  = pd.DataFrame(random_walk, columns=["data"])

n=3
# Find local peaks
df['min'] = df.iloc[signal.argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]]['data']
df['max'] = df.iloc[signal.argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]]['data']

min_points = [t for t in tuple(zip(df.index, df['min'])) if t[1] == t[1]] # zips and removes NaNs
max_points = [t for t in tuple(zip(df.index, df['max'])) if t[1] == t[1]] # zips and removes NaNs
min_end_points = (min_points[0], min_points[-1])
max_end_points = (max_points[0], max_points[-1])

plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c='g')

min_fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit([x[0] for x in min_end_points], [x[1] for x in min_end_points], 1))
max_fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit([x[0] for x in max_end_points], [x[1] for x in max_end_points], 1))

x_proj = np.linspace(0, 30, 30)
plt.plot(df.index, df['data'])
plt.plot(x_proj, min_fit(x_proj), '-r') 
plt.plot(x_proj, max_fit(x_proj), '-b')

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: plot]

If you wanted to project using any other combination of points (or all of them) that is possible as well. You will just need to change which local mins or maxes you are using. You could also create a list of functions and plot them all, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, this does the trick:

```
import random
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

#create random walk
random.seed(1)
random_walk = list()
random_walk.append(-1 if random.random() < 0.5 else 1)
for i in range(1, 20):
    movement = -1 if random.random() < 0.5 else 1
    value = random_walk[i-1] + movement
    random_walk.append(value)


df  = pd.DataFrame(random_walk, columns=["data"])

n=3
# Find local peaks
df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]]['data']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]]['data']

mins = [(k, v) for k, v in list(df[['min']].dropna().to_dict().values())[0].items()]
maxs = [(k, v) for k, v in list(df[['max']].dropna().to_dict().values())[0].items()]
plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c='g')
for previous, current in zip(mins, mins[1:]):
    xs = [a for a,b in [previous, current]]
    ys = [b for a,b in [previous, current]]
    plt.plot(xs, ys)

for previous, current in zip(maxs, maxs[1:]):
    xs = [a for a,b in [previous, current]]
    ys = [b for a,b in [previous, current]]
    plt.plot(xs, ys)

plt.plot(df.index, df['data'])
plt.plot(df['min'], '.r-') 
plt.plot(df['max'], 'xb-')

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]